# Angular 2/4 Adding Scopes

Tags: angular

What is the correct way to add two numerical scopes via the view, such as:

```
<div>{{this.value}} + {{this.othervalue}}</div>
```

Expected output would be:

```
<div>2</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Vega Although it isn't recommended to use `this` in template, it works without any problems (until now).

Answer (score 2):

`{{this.value + this.othervalue}}`

Else, it will outpout the concatenation of these strings.